# direct sum of sub sets

Tags: linear-algebra

K and T are subsets of Linear space V.

**If** $ K \cap T = \varnothing$

**Then**, the sum of $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ is a direct sum.

Well, the answer says its wrong and i'm trying to prove it. I said that:$$ K \cap T = \varnothing$$ which means $$ K \cap T = \{0\}$$ and Sp(K), Sp(T) are sub-spaces of linear space V so $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ is a direct sum(Again, because$ K \cap T = \{0\}$) . But it's wrong, can anyone give me a hint what I fail to understand?

I think that, I can't say for sure that $V = Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ which means even if $ K \cap T = \{0\}$ then I don't know for sure that $V = Sp(K) \oplus Sp(T)$ which may make $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ not a direct sum.

Comment: For subsets the sum need not be direct, for example in $\mathbb{R}$ the subsets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.  However if two subspaces $V,W$ have $V\cap W=0$ then $V+W=V\oplus W$.

Comment: I see the point.

Comment: @Seth Thanks Seth! I got it now, only if it's two subspace and their intsection is zero then their sum is a direct sum, but two subsets may not have an intersection zero.